# Firebase.Server.Timestamp with FireSharp

Tags: c#, firebase

I'm trying to store the current Firebase server timestamp from the C# [Firesharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp) driver. From reading other Firebase client libraries, I can see that a key-value pair of `".sv": "timestamp"` should work, but I can't name a dictionary key in C# as `.sv` starting with a period. So I tried a tuple and got `Item1` and `Item2` as keys.

How do I tell FireSharp to serialise ".sv" "timestamp"?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
var myEntity = new {
    data = { ... },
    timestamp = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        {".sv", "timestamp"},
    };
```

where myEntity gets pushed to Firebase.

Is there a cleaner way?